# Visual Basic Replace

Tags: vb.net

So I want to replace the label ( length of the label ) to underlines/ dashes

[image]

But it only shows it like this, What should I do?

[image]

Answers and codes to improve my work

Comment: Welcome. Please don't show us images of your code but copy&paste it here. I don't know how the screenshot of your application is related to your code. It's currently unclear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the Label to contain the same number of dashes as the number of characters in the string called `hangWord`:

```
lblWord.Text = New String("-", hangWord.Length)
```

If you really want to use a loop, then:

```
lblWord.Text = ""
For i As Integer = 1 To hangWord.Length
    lblWord.Text = lblWord.Text + "-"
Next
```